# Django 1.6 WGSI VirtualEnv

Tags: django

Im trying to configured Django 1.6 with a virtual env with wsgi via apache,

However when I try to access Django my Apache logs show,

```
File "/opt/project/config/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
 from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 ImportError: No module named configurations.wsgi
```

I can import this when Im in the virtualenv,

```
(project)[root@server project]# python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 12 2013, 15:50:41)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>>>
```

My configuration files look like ....

**WSGI.py**

```
(project)[root@server project]# cat /opt/project/config/wsgi.py
import os,sys,site

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_CONFIGURATION', 'Local')

from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

site.addsitedir("/opt/pythonenv/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
sys.path.append('/opt/project/')
sys.path.append('/opt/')
```

**HTTPD.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
        ServerName project.example.com

        ErrorLog logs/apollo-error.log
        CustomLog logs/apollo-access.log common

        LogLevel warn

        # WSGI
        WSGIDaemonProcess django-project threads=10 processes=10 python-path=/opt/project:/production/project/config:/opt/pythonenv/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
        WSGIApplicationGroup django-project
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/project/config/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the virtualenv on your wsgi.py script:

```
[...]
# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Check for more details on http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/